# Textbox input string for the name of an Object created by a Object Factory completely empty

Tags: javascript, html, string, object, oop

I was trying to display the name of the object **Player1** (created with an **Object Factory**) on the game displayer after inserting the name of the player but when I click the button it appears **only the message of the turn without the player's name**, I've discovered that the string of the name become **completely empty** when it tries to display it on the displayer.

```
const Player1TextBox = document.querySelector("#player-1-textbox");
const Player2TextBox = document.querySelector("#player-2-textbox");
const startBtn = document.querySelector("#start-btn");
const gameDisplayer = document.querySelector("#game-displayer");


const Player1 = PlayerFactory(Player1TextBox.value.toString(), "X");

function displayName() {
  gameDisplayer.innerText = `${Player1.getName()}, it's your turn!`;
}
startBtn.addEventListener("click", displayName);


function PlayerFactory(name, sign) {
  const getName = () => {
    return name;
  };
  const getSign = () => {
    return sign;
  };

  return {
    getName,
    getSign
  };
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test #1</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="player-wrapper">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Insert the name of the first player..." id="player-1-textbox">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Insert the name of the second player..." id="player-2-textbox">
      <button id="start-btn">Start</button>
      <h3 id="game-displayer"></h3>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are taking the value from the textbox as soon as the code runs, never updating it.

Comment: I've resolved the issue while waiting for a solution to my problem, yeah i was not updating the value from the textbox during the runtime, thanks :)

Comment: Glad you could solve your issue. Would you please a) create an answer for your question for people who encounter the same issue b) delete your question if you judge that it’s too specific and others won’t encounter the same issue? Thanks!

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Which one? a or b? See [Can I answer my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and [Delete a post](https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4554164-delete-a-post)

Comment: Oh, I have read it but I have less than 15 reputation on stack overflow so I can't answer my own question